# How to unify fonts in references in a thesis class?

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, document-classes

I would like to know what to do in order to unify the fonts in my document, especially in the references. As you can see, there is a problem at least with the arXiv part, which is with a bigger font (and it also appears twice, which is not wanted):

[image]

I am using the thesis template downloaded from [here](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/).
As you can see from my MWE, I changed the font to `libertine`, which I will probably want to keep. I copy-pasted these three lines from somewhere. Also, I (kind of blindly) copy-pasted the part starting with `\newbibmacro` to achieve clickable titles in bibliographic references pointing to the particular bibliography url (works be default in `biblatex` + `hyperref` for eprint fields, but not url's, thanks to cfr for pointing this).

I understand that the solutions is probably not only in editing these lines but in editing the class file `Thesis.cls` from the template.

**So my questions:**

- What spots do I have to edit to achieve the unity of fonts?
- Looking on the code, is there something else I should take care of?
- What `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}` affects?
- I have not seen any problem in the main document as yet, but if you notice anything that could negatively affect the fonts in there, please let me know, too.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)

\usepackage[doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,backref=true]{biblatex} % use of biblatex instead of bibtex (matja add) 

% the following makes bibliography display clickable names of references, pointing to a given doi/url/isbn, in this order of preference
%-------
\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
\iffieldundef{doi}{%
  \iffieldundef{url}{%
    \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
      \iffieldundef{issn}{%
            #1%
           }{%
         \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
       }%
     }{%
   \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
   }%
   }{%
    \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}% 
    }%
  }{%
  \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
 }%
 }
  \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}%
  {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}
  \appto{\biburlsetup}{\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalfont\itshape}}
  \appto{\citesetup}{\normalfont}

% I would like to use this font for everything
%-------
\usepackage{libertine} % new font
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-------

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying


\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@article{Gupta1993,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {arXiv:hep-th/9305052v2},
author = {Gupta, K. S. and Rajeev, S. G.},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevD.48.5940},
eprint = {9305052v2},
file = {:home/matja/MEGAsync/mendeley/1993/Gupta, Rajeev - 1993 - Renormalization in quantum mechanics.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0556-2821},
journal = {Physical Review D},
month = dec,
number = {12},
pages = {5940--5945},
primaryClass = {arXiv:hep-th},
title = "{{Renormalization in quantum mechanics}}",
url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevD.48.5940},
volume = {48},
year = {1993}
} 
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{database.bib}

\begin{document}
This reference has mixed fonts~\cite{Gupta1993}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try `\usepackage[ttscale=0.8]{libertine}`, that will scale down the monospaced font. Experiment to find the scale factor that suits you the best.

Comment: By default, `biblatex` + `hyperref` gets you clickable links anyway, doesn't it? (Obviously not if you've told it to ignore every possible field which might link e.g. doi, url etc.) Probably not just because you give an ISBN but that strikes me as dodgy anyway. Not every book with an ISBN is on google books, so some links will fail if you rely on this.

Comment: @cfr Good point, I've changed the bibentry in my question. `biblatex` + `hyperref` work (by default) only for `eprint` fields. If I have another link in the `url` field of my bibliographic entry (like link.aps.org),  I want to get a clickable title from it, which is what the code does, as the example shows. What solution would you suggest?

Comment: I automatically get links for URL fields, DOI etc. - not just `eprint`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, this is also a solution. But what else might `ttscale` affect? Only the monospaced font? Than this solution should be all right.

Comment: Probably, you aren't using the `\ttfamily` or `\texttt` command anywhere else in your document.  Note that you could also just change the command so you don't use a 'typewriter' font for such links....

Comment: @jon Actually, in the `thesis.cls` file there is the following: `\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}`. Is it connected? Also, how do I change the command to change the 'typewriter' font? Thanks!

Comment: Biblatex loads the `url` package, which allows you to customize the font (see manual). You could use `\urlstyle{same}` (in preamble) to have URLs typeset in whatever the 'current' font is.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Eventually I gave up with trying to get a result 100% according to my wishes, I found it complicated, I think it would require too many changes in the "thesis class". However, the comments above helped to make the result acceptable.

Comment: just a little hint for your next thesis, don't use the template from Sunil. It is very bad (and one of the reason you had trouble here).

Comment: @egreg Do you want to write up anything as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The typewriter font seems indeed to big. It's easy to scale it down with no other effects on fonts: just call the `libertine` package as

```
\usepackage[ttscale=0.8]{libertine}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup :-)